# SQL query to select tablename

Tags: java, mysql

I want to  get all database table names that ends with _tbl like xyz_tbl, pqr_tbl,etc..
in mysql using java.pls help me.. currently my query retreives all tablename but i jst want table names that ends with _tbl.
My code is...

```
public List selectTable() {
    List tableNameList= new ArrayList();

    try {
        DatabaseMetaData dbm = c.conn.getMetaData();
        String[] types = {"TABLE"};
        c.rs = dbm.getTables(null, null, "%", types);
        while (c.rs.next()) {
            tableNameList.add(c.rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
        }            
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());              
    }
    return tableNameList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using a different table name pattern?

You can try this: -

```
c.rs = dbm.getTables(null, null, "%_tbl", types);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql query

```
show tables from tablename like '%_tbl';
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reply to Rohit's post. his answer looks correct.

If you do to JDK documentation for DatabaseMetaData's getTables method following is the signature and documentation comment.

```
ResultSet getTables(String catalog, String schemaPattern, String tableNamePattern, 
                    String[] types) throws SQLException
```

*Parameters:*

> **catalog** - a catalog name; must match the catalog name as it is stored
>   in the database; "" retrieves those without a catalog; null means that
>   the catalog name should not be used to narrow the search 
>   **schemaPattern**
>   - a schema name pattern; must match the schema name as it is stored in the database; "" retrieves those without a schema; null means that the
>   schema name should not be used to narrow the search 
> **tableNamePattern** -
>   a table name pattern; must match the table name as it is stored in the
>   database 
> **types** - a list of table types, which must be from the list of
>   table types returned from getTableTypes(),to include; null returns all
>   types

In this case using `%_tbl` should work.

Comment: @vishaljain.. Yeah you need at least `50 reputations` to comment on someone's post.

Comment: Hey thanks Rohit... Atleast I can comment on my post n answer :)

Comment: @vishaljain.. You will soon get enough priviledge to do various task here on SO, while you post good answers and ask good questions. Best of Luck, and enjoy the journey :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the String.endsWith() method to check if the table name ends with "_tbl".

For example inside your while loop:

```
 while (c.rs.next())
 {
      String tableName = c.rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
      if(tableName.endsWith("_tbl"))
      {
          tableNameList.add(c.rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
      }
 }
```